# unmet dependencies with QT

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I can't install any more packages in my Ubuntu 12. I tried `apt-get install -f`, and many others tricks like this, but no progress in finding a solution.

Here is the broken packages belonging to Qt:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
qdbus: Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
       Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
       Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
qt4-demos: Depends: libgl1 but it is a virtual package
           Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
           Depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
           Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
           Depends: libqt4-help (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
           Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
           Depends: libqt4-opengl (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
           Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
           Depends: libqt4-scripttools (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is
```

---

.. and other ones belonging to Qt. (Useless I think to past them all, unless you need them )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just :

- Opened Synaptic;
- Filtered by broken packages;
- And completely removed them.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have packages the installation of which did not go right. Try to clean up those by using apt or dpkg.